# Radius in Foursquare Venues search

Tags: android, foursquare

How do i put radius inside venues search method?

```
Result<VenuesSearchResult> result = foursquareApi.venuesSearch(LAT_LONG, null, null, null, "clothing", 20, null, null, null, null, null);
```

Radius isn't specifically mentioned anywhere among venuesSearch() parameters:

> Result fi.foyt.foursquare.api.FoursquareApi.venuesSearch(String ll, Double llAcc, Double alt, Double altAcc, String query, Integer limit, String intent, String categoryId, String url, String providerId, String linkedId) throws FoursquareApiException

Is it supposed to be put inside String intent? And how?

BTW, radius IS mentioned in [Foursquare docs](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/search).

I am using this library: [Foursquare API Java](https://code.google.com/p/foursquare-api-java/), which is also suggested by Foursquare itself.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to contact the maintainer of whatever android library you're using to update the method to accept the field. Alternatively, you can just edit your local copy and send a suggested patch to the maintainer.

Comment: Ok, I'm using the only library that's listed under Java: https://developer.foursquare.com/resources/libraries. So in current form it isn't possible to set radius? Is anybody working with that library?

Answer (score 0):

it may help you.

https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/search

also see this

getFoursquareApi().venuesSearch(ll, llAcc, alt, altAcc, query, limit, intent, categoryId, url, providerId, linkedId)

use these jar file in your app:

foursquare-api-1.0.0.jar

Comment: I am using this jar file. Although there's a GET/POST problem in Android ICS... I wish Foursquare would take care of their APIs...